# how to redirect on the requested scheme (http or https)

Tags: haproxy

I'm redirecting to some domain based on an acl condition but I want the user to end up on either `http` or `https` depending on the scheme/protocol of their request. I've managed to do that with the 2 lines shown bellow, but I'd like to convert them to just 1 line:

```
http-request redirect code 301 location http://www.example.com%[url] if acl_whatever !{ ssl_fc }
http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.example.com%[url] if acl_whatever { ssl_fc }
```

Ideally I'd like to redirect to something like `%[scheme]://www.example.com%[url]` but `%[scheme]` does not exist.

Is there a variable or function which can return `http` or `https` so I do not have to repeat the rule twice? Maybe by somehow setting a variable containing the scheme or maybe by using the value of `%[ssl_fc]` which is 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `http-request set-var` and `%[var(name)]`:

```
http-request set-var(req.scheme) str(https) if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-var(req.scheme) str(http) if ! { ssl_fc }
http-request redirect code 301 location %[var(req.scheme)]://www.example.com%[url] if acl_whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

### As an addition:

If the request schema is needed in the response, `txn` scope must be used instead of `req`.

**For example:**

```
frontend http_awesome_frontend


http-request set-var(txn.scheme) str(https) if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-var(txn.scheme) str(http) if !{ ssl_fc }


# Outer frontend response:

http-response add-header X-Original-Proto %[var(txn.scheme)]
```

> All variables are scoped, meaning they can only be accessed within the same or larger scope. When you set a variable, you prefix its names with a scope. The scope can be any of the following:
>
> - **proc**: variable is available during all phases
> - **sess**: variable is available during a client's entire TCP session
> - **txn**: variable is available during an entire HTTP request-response transaction
> - **req**: variable is available during the HTTP request phase only
> - **res**: variable is available during the HTTP response phase only
>
> Sources: [HA Proxy Documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/configuration/variables/syntax/)